# Deleting lines in external text files

Tags: python-2.7

Hi please how can I iterate over the lines in an external file, identify those with a 0 at the last index of each line and delete those lines while retrieving the ones not deleted. ie

```
input.txt = 1001 1001 0 
            1001 1002 0 
            1001 1003 0.058529
            ...
            ...
            ...
            9007 9007 0.0789
```

I tried this

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
    o_d = line.split()
    if o_d[-1] == '0':
        o_d.pop()
        print o_d
```

I know this will only take out the 0 in every line with a zero, I however need help with delete the entire line where the 0 appears and then write the file back with the lines that don't have a zero.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close to your code. The only gotcha is that you need to call `str.strip`, since `readlines` includes the trailing newline.

Rather than attempting to modify the file in place, this code first reads in all of the data, and then writes all of the lines that end with a '0'.

```
# Read in the source data
with open('input.txt', 'r') as handle:
    lines = handle.readlines()
# Open the output file
with open('input.txt', 'w') as handle:
    # Examine each line of the source data
    for line in lines:
        # If it doesn't end with a '0', write it
        if line.strip()[-1] != '0':
            handle.write(line)
```

One way to format the last line as you requested is to split the line into the separate values, put them into a tuple, and insert them into a format string, which would then be written. For example:

```
"[(%s,%s,{%s})]" % tuple(line.split())
```

So the complete code would be

```
# Read in the source data
with open('input.txt', 'r') as handle:
    lines = handle.readlines()
# Open the output file
with open('input.txt', 'w') as handle:
    # Examine each line of the source data
    for line in lines:
        # If it doesn't end with a '0', write it
        if line.strip()[-1] != '0':
            line.split()
            handle.write("[(%s,%s,{%s})]" % tuple(line.split()))
```

Comment: Please provide at least some explanation along with your code for future reference/clarity.

Comment: @Moshe it works well. Please can you be of help with d last line ie the handle.write(line). if I need to format the output to look like this [(1001,10001,{0.058529})] how can that be done. Thanks